# The OSRM server returned an error: Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler): object 'res' not found

Tags: r, docker, osrm

I run my own OSRM server and use OSRM R package.

[OSRM server run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSYrt.png)

but when I want to get `osrmTable` I get this error:

The OSRM server returned an error:

> Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler): object
> 'res' not found

and my code is this:

```
get_OSRMTable = osrmTable(route,osrm.server = "http://0.0.0.0:5000/",osrm.profile = ("car"), measure = c("distance","duration"))
```